# How can I disable some PopupMenu items in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I use the following Code B to click a button to open a  `PopupMenu`.

The `PopupMenu` include Edit, Delete and Setting items.

I hope the Edit and Delete items are disabled or disappear when there is no record,  maybe it's like Code A,  how can I write the code ?

**Code A**

```
popup.setOnMenuItemBeforePopup {
  if (recordCount==0){
    R.id.popMenuMoreEdit.disable
    R.id.popMenuMoreDelete.disbale
  }
}
```

**Code B**

```
    private fun setControls(){       
        btnMore.setOnClickListener (View.OnClickListener { v -> showPopup(v, mContext) })
    }

    fun showPopup(v: View, mContext: Context) {
        val popup = PopupMenu(mContext, v)
        popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_more)

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            item -> handleMenu(item, mContext)
        }

        popup.show()
    }


   private fun handleMenu(item: MenuItem, mContext: Context): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {

            R.id.popMenuMoreEdit -> {

                return true
            }

            R.id.popMenuMoreDelete -> {

                return true
            }

            R.id.popMenuMoreBackupSetting-> {

                return true
            }

        }
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply have to get ahold of the `MenuItem` instances in your `PopupMenu` and set them enabled/disabled when appropriate.

For example (assuming your `PopupMenu` instance is called `popup`):

```
popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_more)

// ...

if (recordCount == 0){
    // assuming popMenuMoreEdit and popMenuMoreDelete are item IDs in menu_more
    popup.menu.findItem(R.id.popMenuMoreEdit).isEnabled = false
    popup.menu.findItem(R.id.popMenuMoreDelete).isEnabled = false
}
```